# Python - Adding Decimal places to elements in cvs file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

When exporting a CSV file from a data simulation, we lost the decimal places that were associated with the data recorded, making our plots and values inaccurate.

When the data was collected, it was imported into excel and then exported as a CSV. There were originally decimal values with the data (e.g. 1356.00000), but they were not exported as such in the CSV data. I'm using a curve_fit for these values, and I have figured out the precision was greatly reduced with the loss of the decimal values. So that's why I want to add decimal points to each element in the data set.

Is there any way to fix this so that all the values elements in the array are outputted as an array with decimal values?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import csv

DecayTime = []
DecayCount = []

with open('Half_Life_Run_Decay.csv', 'r') as h:
    reader = csv.reader(h, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        DecayTime4.append(row[0])
        DecayCount4.append(row[1])

DecayTime = np.array(DecayTime) 
DecayCount = np.array(DecayCount)
```

Comment: `csv.reader` reads them rows as strings. Try casting them to `float` before appending to `DecayTime[]`.

Comment: is the csv file inaccurate? There is no way to take a csv file with inaccurate/imprecise  data and fix the accuracy/precision.  On the other hand if you mean precision is lost while loading the csv file your question needs clarification.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen When the data was collected, it was imported into excel, to where the the data was exported as a cvs. There were originally decimal values with the data (ie 1356.00000), but they were not exported with the data. I'm using a curve_fit for these values, and I have figured out the precision was  greatly lost with the lost of the decimal values. So thats why I want to add decimal points with each element in the data set.

Comment: If the data lost precision during the `excel -> csv` stage you are showing us the wrong code, and by "not exported with the data" do you mean the actual number did export but as `1256.0` instead of full precision?

Comment: numpy.savetxt would be a good option, especially if you already have scipy in your workflow.. You will have fill control on the output format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your problem is so much about precision as it is about data type.  Is all your data being interpreted as integers?

Try converting your row into floating point before accessing its columns:

```
row = map(float, row)
```

Or if you just want to change the strings:

```
row = map(lambda s: s + ".0000", row)
```

Comment: The problem is precision. I have runs where their the decimal places are preserved like 256.00000 and 345.00000 to which has given me the correct values and plots when running it through curve_fit. I'm just wanting to know how to for loop this by adding the decimal places. You could have each element in the array to be with 0.0001 even.

Comment: Funnily enough the default data type for `numpy` arrays is `float`. By that argument, your `curve_fit` should've run fine.

Comment: @Quirk yeah, I'm still not sure if this is a data type issue.  I'm not that familiar with numpy, but the `curve_fit` does take a function as an argument that could possibly be treating the ints as ints.  I figured let the OP try by adding ".0000" and see if it actually solves the problem.